# Return only Child resolver Error in GraphQL

Tags: error-handling, graphql, apollo, prisma, prisma-graphql

Following is the schema

```
type Payload {
    name: String!
    address: String!
    phone: String
}

type Mutation {
    login(username: String!, password: String!): Payload!
}
```

Following is the resolver for Payload

```
Payload: {
    user: {
        resolve: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
            // Some logic here
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

When I throw error from child resolver (here payload resolver) graphql still return all payload data return from Parent resolver and for only user field it return error. Can we change this behaviour to return only error which child resolver throws ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. According to the [GraphQL Response Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/blob/master/spec/Section%207%20--%20Response.md#response):

- If any `data` is resolved and and `error` is thrown, both will be returned by the server.

Comment: Is there any other way to modify parent object in child object before returning ?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't access or modify the parent object(resolver) from the child(resolver).

Comment: Ok. Can we handle the error in Schema Stitching resolver and return only error.

Comment: Not really sure about that.